Issue with custom QGIS process algorithm
I have a written a custom processing algorithm which iterates features within one vector layer and eliminates polygons in the second that are within each feature from the first under a specific size. I want to provide some control to the process of eliminating polygons.


Below is my code used for the custom algorithm:
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                       QgsFeatureSink,
                       QgsFeatureRequest,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingParameterString,
                       QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer,
                       QgsProcessingParameterEnum,
                       QgsProcessingParameterNumber,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink)
from qgis import processing

class EliminatePolygonsByMaskProcessingAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    INPUT = 'INPUT'
    MASK = 'MASK'
    UNIT = 'UNIT'
    THRESHOLD = 'THRESHOLD'
    MERGE = 'MERGE'
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'

    def tr(self, string):
        """
        Returns a translatable string with the self.tr() function.
        """
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    def createInstance(self):
        return EliminatePolygonsByMaskProcessingAlgorithm()

    def name(self):
        return 'eliminate_polygons_by_mask_layer'

    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr('Eliminate Polygons by Mask Layer')

    def group(self):
        return self.tr('HOIIV')

    def groupId(self):
        return 'hoiiv'

    def shortHelpString(self):
        return self.tr("Example algorithm short description")

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):

        # We add the input vector. It can have any kind of
        # geometry.
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer(
                self.INPUT,
                self.tr('Input layer'),
                [QgsProcessing.SourceType.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]
            )
        )
        
        # We add the mask vector. It can have any kind of
        # geometry.
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer(
                self.MASK,
                self.tr('Mask layer'),
                [QgsProcessing.SourceType.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]
            )
        )

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterEnum(
                self.UNIT,
                self.tr('Measurement'),
                options=['Area','Perimeter'], 
                allowMultiple=False, 
                usesStaticStrings=False, 
                defaultValue=[1]
            )
        )

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterNumber(
                self.THRESHOLD,
                self.tr('Eliminate polygons less than or equal to'),
                type=QgsProcessingParameterNumber.Integer, 
                minValue=0, 
                defaultValue=60000
            )
        )

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterEnum(
                self.MERGE,
                self.tr('Merge boundary by'),
                options=['Largest Area','Smallest Area','Largest Common Boundary'], 
                allowMultiple=False, 
                usesStaticStrings=False, 
                defaultValue=[1]
            )
        )

        # We add a feature sink in which to store our processed features (this
        # usually takes the form of a newly created vector layer when the
        # algorithm is run in QGIS).
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
                self.OUTPUT,
                self.tr('Output layer'),
                type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon
            )
        )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        """
        Here is where the processing itself takes place.
        """

        # Retrieve the feature source and sink. The 'dest_id' variable is used
        # to uniquely identify the feature sink, and must be included in the
        # dictionary returned by the processAlgorithm function.
        source = self.parameterAsVectorLayer(
            parameters,
            self.INPUT,
            context
        )
        
        mask = self.parameterAsVectorLayer(
            parameters,
            self.MASK,
            context
        )
        
        unitType = self.parameterAsString(
            parameters,
            self.UNIT,
            context
        )
        
        limit = self.parameterAsString(
            parameters,
            self.THRESHOLD,
            context
        )
        
        if source is None:
            raise QgsProcessingException(self.invalidSourceError(parameters, self.INPUT))

        (sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(
            parameters,
            self.OUTPUT,
            context,
            source.fields(),
            source.wkbType(),
            source.sourceCrs()
        )

        # Send some information to the user
        feedback.pushInfo(f'CRS is {source.sourceCrs().authid()}')

        if sink is None:
            raise QgsProcessingException(self.invalidSinkError(parameters, self.OUTPUT))
            
        # Compute the number of steps to display within the progress bar and
        # get features from source
        total = 100.0 / mask.featureCount() if mask.featureCount() else 0
        features = mask.getFeatures()

        feedback.pushInfo('Processing features')

        for feature in mask.getFeatures():            

            # Stop the algorithm if cancel button has been clicked
            if feedback.isCanceled():
                break
                
            # Select each feature from the mask layer
            mask.select(feature.id())               
        
            # Extract selected features
            extract_feature =  processing.run("native:saveselectedfeatures", {
                'INPUT': mask,
                'OUTPUT':'memory:'
            }, context=context, feedback=feedback)['OUTPUT']
                              
            # Extract by location
            extract_location =  processing.run("native:extractbylocation", {
                'INPUT': source,
                'INTERSECT': extract_feature,
                'PREDICATE': [6],  # are within
                'OUTPUT':'memory:'
            }, context=context, feedback=feedback)['OUTPUT']
            
            # Select by expression
            select_expression =  processing.run("qgis:selectbyexpression", {
                'INPUT': extract_location,
                'EXPRESSION': 'if( ' + unitType + ' = 0, $area <= ' + limit + ', $perimeter <= ' + limit + ' )',
                'METHOD': 0,  # creating new selection
            }, context=context, feedback=feedback)['OUTPUT']       

            # Eliminate selected polygons
            eliminated_polys =  processing.run("qgis:eliminateselectedpolygons", {
                'INPUT': select_expression,
                'MODE': parameters[self.MERGE],
                'OUTPUT':'memory:'
            }, context=context, feedback=feedback)['OUTPUT']            
          
            #if eliminated_polys.featureCount() = 0:
                #sink.addFeatures(extract_location.getFeatures(), QgsFeatureSink.Flag.FastInsert)
            #else:
            sink.addFeatures(eliminated_polys.getFeatures(), QgsFeatureSink.Flag.FastInsert)

            # DeSelect the feature from the mask layer
            mask.deselect(feature.id()) 

            # Update the progress bar
            feedback.setProgress(int(feature.id() * total))
                        
        return {self. OUTPUT: dest_id}

If I execute this script without the is_child_algorithm=True (as suggested) against each process using 2 layers I manually prepared (see screenshots), it completes. To accelerate my workflow I would like to use this script in a model which basically creates the 2 layers automatically and executes the script above.
The code for the model exported to Python:
"""
Model exported as python.
Name : Extract Country
Group : 
With QGIS : 33602
"""

from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterString
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterBoolean
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterEnum
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterNumber
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
from qgis.core import QgsExpression
import processing


class ExtractCountry(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('input_layer', 'Input layer', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('mask_layer', 'Mask layer', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterString('country_code', 'Country code', multiLine=False, defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterBoolean('eliminate_polygons_less_than', 'Eliminate polygons less than', defaultValue=True))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterEnum('measurement', 'Measurement', options=['Area','Perimeter'], allowMultiple=False, usesStaticStrings=False, defaultValue=[1]))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterNumber('eliminate_polygons_less_than_or_equal_to', 'Eliminate polygons less than or equal to', type=QgsProcessingParameterNumber.Integer, minValue=0, defaultValue=60000))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterEnum('merge_boundary_by', 'Merge boundary by', options=['Largest Area','Smallest Area','Largest Common Boundary'], allowMultiple=False, usesStaticStrings=False, defaultValue=[2]))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Output', 'Output', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(3, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Extract Mask by attribute
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD': 'GID_0',
            'INPUT': parameters['mask_layer'],
            'OPERATOR': 0,  # =
            'VALUE': QgsExpression('upper (@country_code)').evaluate(),
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtractMaskByAttribute'] = processing.run('native:extractbyattribute', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract Input by attribute
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD': 'GID_0',
            'INPUT': parameters['input_layer'],
            'OPERATOR': 0,  # =
            'VALUE': QgsExpression('upper (@country_code)').evaluate(),
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtractInputByAttribute'] = processing.run('native:extractbyattribute', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(2)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Eliminate Polygons by Mask Layer
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['ExtractInputByAttribute']['OUTPUT'],
            'MASK': outputs['ExtractMaskByAttribute']['OUTPUT'],
            'MERGE': parameters['merge_boundary_by'],
            'THRESHOLD': parameters['eliminate_polygons_less_than_or_equal_to'],
            'UNIT': parameters['measurement'],
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Output']
        }
        outputs['EliminatePolygonsByMaskLayer'] = processing.run('script:eliminate_polygons_by_mask_layer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Output'] = outputs['EliminatePolygonsByMaskLayer']['OUTPUT']
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'Extract Country'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'Extract Country'

    def group(self):
        return ''

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def createInstance(self):
        return ExtractCountry()
        

However, if I execute the model still without the is_child_algorithm=True I get the following error message:

Error encountered while running Eliminate Polygons by Mask Layer:
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS
3.36.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\EliminateSelection.py",
line 225, in processAlgorithm if not processLayer.commitChanges():
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of
type QgsVectorLayer has been deleted

If I execute the model with the is_child_algorithm=True I get the following QGIS crash with the following dump:

Report Details
Python Stack Trace ``` Windows fatal exception: access violation
Current thread 0x00005b5c (most recent call first):   File
"C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS
3.36.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\AlgorithmExecutor.py",
line 70 in execute
results, ok = alg.run(parameters, context, feedback, {}, False)   File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS
3.36.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 192 in runAlgorithm
ret, results = execute(alg, parameters, context, feedback, catch_exceptions=False)   File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS
3.36.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 109 in run
return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)   File
"C:\Users\steve\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\processing\scripts\Eliminate
Polygons by Mask Layer.py", line 261 in processAlgorithm
select_expression =  processing.run("qgis:selectbyexpression", {
Thread 0x00000d30 (most recent call first):   File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS
3.36.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\modeler\ModelerDialog.py",
line 152 in runModel
dlg.exec() ```
Stack Trace

PyInit_QtCore : PyInit_sip : PyInit_sip :
pdal::StreamPointTable::reset : pdal::PointView::table :
QgsProcessingAlgorithm::runPrepared : QgsProcessingAlgorithm::run :
pdal::PointView::table : PyLong_FromString : PyObject_Vectorcall :
PyObject_Vectorcall : PyEval_EvalFrameDefault : PyFunction_Vectorcall
: PyArg_CheckPositional : PyObject_Call : PyObject_Call : PyInit_sip :
PyInit_sip : pdal::StreamPointTable::reset : pdal::PointView::table :
QgsProcessingAlgorithm::runPrepared :
QgsProcessingModelAlgorithm::processAlgorithm :
QgsProcessingAlgorithm::runPrepared : QgsProcessingAlgRunnerTask::run
: pdal::PointView::table : QgsTask::start : QThreadPoolPrivate::reset
: QThread::start : BaseThreadInitThunk : RtlUserThreadStart : ```



**QGIS Info** QGIS Version: 3.36.2-Maidenhead QGIS code revision: 6d250527 Compiled against Qt: 5.15.13 Running against Qt: 5.15.13
Compiled against GDAL: 3.8.5 Running against GDAL: 3.8.5



**System Info** CPU Type: x86_64 Kernel Type: winnt Kernel Version: 10.0.22631


What have I done wrong?

Question heavily edited.
Think I may have accidentally deleted a comment - apologies to that person!!
